# Include Html file into Html

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-4, include

I try to include Html file into Html But doesn't work. anyone can help me

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script> 
    $(function(){
      $("#DivContent").load("second.html"); 
    });
</script> 

<div id="DivContent"></div>
```

Comment: Have you checked developer tools for any errors in network/console tab ?

Comment: Are the two files in the same folder?

Comment: heres the error

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///C:/Users/troilus/Downloads/test.html' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, brave, chrome-untrusted, https.
jquery.min.js:2 GET file:///C:/Users/troilus/Downloads/test.html net::ERR_FAILED

Comment: Are you running it locally? Is it `second.html` or `test.html`?

Comment: Does either of these answer your question? [Local xml blocked by cors policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55281250/local-xml-blocked-by-cors-policy) or [Cross origin issue for jQuery .load() for a locally placed file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37985922/cross-origin-issue-for-jquery-load-for-a-locally-placed-file)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you need a local server in order to make it work. Nowadays browsers are strongly restricting file reading through XHR from origin null (aka no web server). Try to use any servers, such as `express.js`, Node's `http`, or any php server. Your error will vanish, if the file exists.